# How to get a balance panel from an unbalanced one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an unbalanced panel data, in which data of countries covers different time range. For example, the value of country A is from 1996 to 2001, value of country B is from 2000 to 2006, the value of country C is from 1996 to 2006. I would like to select the data of the countries whose data is from 1996 to 2006, which is to drop data from country A and country B. So if the time range of data of a country is a subset of 1996~2006, then this country should be dropped, while those whose time range equals or is larger than 1996~2006 should be kept, and the final result should be a balanced panel.
I`d like to use python 3.6 (especially pandas) to solve this. The original data structure is as follows:

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful to provide a sample of code than an image.  That way people can paste it into their own computers when writing a solution.